# List - use in a command

Tags: python

I got output from a device and the output is stored in below variable as list

```
output = ['Gig 5/1', 'Gig 5/37', 'Gig 6/37', 'Gig 5/7', 'Gig 6/3', 'Gig 5/3']
```

Again I need to run different command on same device by selecting the indexes from output.

```
command = 'show interface '+output[0]
```

If I enter the index value I get the output. For some devices the output index count keeps changing. Need to execute the command without mentioning the exact index and also it need to break once all the indexes are executed. Finally either the result need to be stored in a single variable or whenever a command is executed it need to store in new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code example that uses iteration and subprocess to do the work:

```
import subprocess

output = ['Gig 5/1', 'Gig 5/37', 'Gig 6/37', 'Gig 5/7', 'Gig 6/3', 'Gig 5/3']

for item in output:
    subprocess.call(('show', 'interface', item))
```

This is assuming these are system commands.  If not you will have to replace `subprocess` with something more appropriate.

---

Another way is to use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
output = {
  'Gig 5/1': None,
  'Gig 5/37': None, 
  'Gig 6/37': None, 
  'Gig 5/7': None, 
  'Gig 6/3': None, 
  'Gig 5/3': None,
  }

for key in output:
  output[key] = do_something_with(key)
```

The output will be like:

```
{
  'Gig 5/1': "result for Gig 5/1",
  'Gig 5/37': "result for Gig 5/37",
}
```

Or you can access it like:

```
for interface, value in output.items():
  print(interface, value)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, those are network devices. I was able to get it done by using append. All the output is stored in a single variable. Is it possible to store the result in different variable whenever the command is executed?

Comment: @selvamsamymuthu, I appended to my answer with a way to store this in the dictionary.